# How to match bold markdown if it isn't preceded with a backslash?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I'm looking to match bolded markdown. Here are some examples:

`qwer *asdf* zxcv` matches `*asdf*`

`qwer*asdf*zxcv` matches `*asdf*`

`qwer \*asdf* zxcv` does not match

`*qwer* asdf zxcv` matches `*qwer*`

A negative look behind like this `(?<!\\)\*(.*)\*` works.

Except there is no browser support in Firefox, so I cannot use it.

Similarly, I can get very close with `(^|[^\\])\*(.*)\*`

The issue is that there are two capture groups, and I need the index of the second capture group, and Javascript only returns the index of the first capture group. I can bandaid it in this case by just adding 1, but in other cases this hack will not work.

My reasoning for doing this is that I'm trying to replace a small subset of Markdown with React components. As an example, I'm trying to convert this string:

`qwer *asdf* zxcv *123*`

Into this array:

`[ "qwer ", <strong>asdf</strong>, " zxcv ", <strong>123</strong> ]`

Where the second and fourth elements are created via JSX and included as array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to take into account that when a backslash occurs before an asterisk, it may be one that is itself escaped by a backslash, and in that case the asterisk *should* be considered the start of bold markup. Except if that one is also preceded by a backslash,...etc.

So I would suggest this regular expression:

`((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\.)*)\*((\\.|[^*])*)\*`

If the purpose is to replace these with tags, like `<strong> ... </strong>`, then just use JavaScript's `replace` as follows:

```js
let s = String.raw`now *this is bold*, and \\*this too\\*, but \\\*this\* not`;
console.log(s);

let regex = /((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\.)*)\*((\\.|[^*])*)\*/g;
let res = s.replace(regex, "$1<strong>$2</strong>");
console.log(res);
```

If the bolded words should be converted to a React component and stored in an array with the other pieces of plain text, then you could use `split` and `map`:

```
let s = String.raw`now *this is bold*, and \\*this too\\*, but \\\*this\* not`;
console.log(s);

let regex = /((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\.)*)\*((?:\\.|[^*])*)\*/g;
let res = s.split(regex).map((s, i) =>
    i%3 === 2 ? React.createComponent("strong", {}, s) : s
);
```

Since there are two capture groups in the "delimiter" for the `split` call, one having the preceding character(s) and the second the word itself, every third item in the `split` result is a word to be bolded, hence the `i%3` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use string replace, because the items have to be real JSX items in an array. This is because I replace some markup with custom React components.

Comment: `replace` takes a callback as second argument in which you can inject whatever you want.

Comment: Yeah but the return value of the callback function has to be a string, no? As far as I know I can't inject literal React components or arrays as replacements for the string.

Comment: If you edit your question and show your react code as you currently have it, I can possibly propose how to align it with this.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that now. One moment

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: This is insanely impressive! Thank you!!

Comment: The only issue is that I also want to then run an italics regex on it (after I run the bold one), but now it is no longer a string.. But I'll try to figure something out.

Comment: That's going to be tricky, since that could also be nested inside a bold markup. But I suggest you have a go at it, and if you bump into an issue, make it a new question.

Comment: Okie dokie I'll work on it for another 30 minutes or so and if I'm still stuck I'll make another question.

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203236/how-to-parse-a-small-subset-of-markdown-into-react-components

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`/(?:^|[^\\])(\*[^*]+[^\\]\*)/`

The only capturing group there is the string surrounded by *'s.

Comment: Ah, didn't know non-capture groups existed like that. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! If you start a group with `?:` it makes it non-capturing.

Comment: Ah darn, there's still the original problem I had with my regex in the OP in that the `index` of the JavaScript match result refers to the full match, which includes the space. So it's still off-by-one.

Comment: What are you using the index for? The `match` function will return the matching capture group for you. Perhaps there's a better way to do whatever you're doing with that index. *EDIT* If you really need the index, you can make that first group capturing by removing the `?:` and then take the index plus the length of the first capture.

Comment: I'm trying to replace that item in the string with a React component. An alternative approach I suppose could be something like `(.*)(?:^|[^\\])(\*[^*]+[^\\]\*)(.*)`, and then I can do `[ group(1), <strong>group(2)</strong>, group(3) ]`, but that one still has the problem where it's missing that one character so it won't reconstruct properly.

Comment: `/(^|[^\\])(\*[^*]+[^\\]\*)/ ` -- group 1 (match index 0) will contain the character before the bold asterisk or an empty string if the string starts with the bold asterisk; group 2 (match index 1) will contain just the bold part. You can combine them as needed, or grab the length of the preceding character for index math.